# List EC2 volumes in Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I want to list all volumes attached to my EC2 instance.

I can list volumes with my code:

```
conn = EC2Connection()
attribute = get_instance_metadata()
region=attribute['local-hostname'].split('.')[1]
inst_id = attribute['instance-id']
aws = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region)
volume=attribute['local-hostname']
volumes = str(aws.get_all_volumes(filters={'attachment.instance-id': inst_id}))
```

But this results in:

```
[vol-35b0b5fa, Volume:vol-6cbbbea3]
```

I need something like:

```
vol-35b0b5fa
vol-6cbbbea3
```

Answer (score 25):

If you are using Boto3 library then here is the command to list out all attached volumes

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')
volumes = ec2.volumes.all() # If you want to list out all volumes
volumes = ec2.volumes.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'status', 'Values': ['in-use']}]) # if you want to list out only attached volumes
[volume for volume in volumes]
```

Answer (score 4):

The `get_all_volumes` call in boto returns a list of `Volume` objects.  If all you need is the ID of the volume, you can get that using the `id` attribute of the `Volume` object:

```
import boto.ec2
ec2 = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region_name)
volumes = ec2.get_all_volumes()
volume_ids = [v.id for v in volumes]
```

The variable `volume_ids` would now be a list of strings where each string is the ID of one of the volumes.

Answer (score 3):

I think here the requirement is just to iterate over the list with v.id:
Just add this to your code:

```
for v in volumes:
    print v.id
```

Comment: To make it more shorter you can simply do

    [v.id for v in volumes]

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to retrieve volumes would be as follows

```py
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',"us-west-1")
volume = ec2.volumes.all()
for vol in volume:
    print(vol.id)
    print(vol.tags)
```