# Code times out when trying to run as a lambda function in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Below is my code and I am hoping someone can help me with the cleaning up the code and making it more effiencient.  Basically, the code should iterate through all the volumes in my AWS account and then list all untagged volumes and then send out an email.  However, it times out when running it as a lambda function in AWS but if i run it locally, it will take over 30 mins to complete (however it does complete).  Im sure its iterating through things it doesnt need.

Also if I print the ec2_instances list, I can see duplicate values, so I want to only have unique values so that its not repeating the script for each ec2 instance.

```
import logging
import boto3
from smtplib import SMTP, SMTPException
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

session = boto3.Session(profile_name="prod")
client = session.client('ec2')

untagged_volumes = []
detached_volumes = []
ec2_instances = []

response = client.describe_volumes()

for volume in response['Volumes']:
    if 'Tags' in str(volume):
        continue
    else:
        if 'available' in str(volume):
            detached_volumes.append(volume['VolumeId'])
        else:
            untagged_volumes.append(volume['VolumeId'])
            untagged_volumes.append(volume['Attachments'][0]['InstanceId'])
            ec2_instances.append(volume['Attachments'][0]['InstanceId'])

unique_instances = list(set(ec2_instances))

# Create the msg body.
msg_body_list = []
for instance in unique_instances:
    desc_instance = client.describe_instances()

    # append to the msg_body_list the lines that we would like to show on the email
    msg_body_list.append("VolumeID: {}".format(desc_instance['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['BlockDeviceMappings'][0]['Ebs']['VolumeId']))
    msg_body_list.append("Attached Instance: {}".format(desc_instance['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']))

    # if there are tags, we will append it as singles lines as far we have tags
    if 'Tags' in desc_instance['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]:
        msg_body_list.append("Tags:")
        for tag in desc_instance['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['Tags']:
            msg_body_list.append("    Key: {} | Value: {}".format(tag['Key'], tag['Value']))
    # in case we don't have tags, just append no tags.
    else:
        msg_body_list.append("Tags: no tags")
        msg_body_list.append("--------------------")

# send email
mail_from = "xxx@xxx.com"
mail_to = 'xxx@xxx.com'

msg = MIMEText("\n".join(msg_body_list))
msg["Subject"] = "EBS Tagged Instance Report for"
msg["From"] = mail_from
msg["To"] = mail_to

try:
    server = SMTP('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'xx')
    server.sendmail(mail_from, mail_to.split(','), msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
    print('Email sent')
except SMTPException:
    print('ERROR! Unable to send mail')
```

Comment: At first look I think you can start using boto3 resources rather than `client` as suggested by the docs. The functions there are faster and better suited for out-of-the-box usage. Start with refactoring this, i.e. check the comment with 7 upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002826/list-ec2-volumes-in-boto

Comment: What is "unique_list" and "instance"? You iterate through "unique_list" and assign each item as "instance" but then don't use either

Comment: unique_list was something i used to test.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I have edited the code.

Comment: Anyone able to help?  I've managed to create a new list with just unique instanceid's (code updated to reflect this), but the code still takes forever to run (i've been told by some that it could be because of the describe_instances) and when it does complete eventually, it sends me an email with information for the same instance multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions have a time limit of 15 minutes. That is the reason for the timeout - if you need to run scripts for longer, look up [AWS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/).

Comment: Fargate is not an option for us at the moment.  I know the timeout of 15 mins for Lambda, but i think that there may be something wrong with my script if it is taking longer than that, which is why Im asking for help