# List all EBS volumes in an AWS Account

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-ebs

I am trying to get a list of all the EBS volumes in an AWS account. I'm using Python 3 and boto3 version 1.10.34.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002826/list-ec2-volumes-in-boto) with some suggestions but neither of them work.

I'm setting the `ec2_client` like this:
    import boto3
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account,region_name='us-east-1')
    ec2_client = session.client('ec2')

If I try `volumes = ec2_client.volumes.all()` I get back `AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'volumes'`.

If I try `volumes = ec2_client.get_all_volumes()`I get back `AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'get_all_volumes'`.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: the EC2 Client object has no `get_all_volumes` method

Comment: Check the documentation. There should be something like describe_ebs_volumes.

Comment: Yeah thanks. The method is actually `describe_volumes()`. I found it and it works. Thanks for playing! :)

Comment: your first call should have worked technically looking at the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.volumes)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use `paginator` when you need to describe "**all**" volumes.
If you have more than 1000 volumes, `describe_volumes()` will not describe all volumes, just the first 1000.

Let me quote the reference documentation below.

> Some AWS operations return results that are incomplete and require
>   subsequent requests in order to attain the entire result set. The
>   process of sending subsequent requests to continue where a previous
>   request left off is called pagination. For example, the list_objects
>   operation of Amazon S3 returns up to 1000 objects at a time, and you
>   must send subsequent requests with the appropriate Marker in order to
>   retrieve the next page of results.
>
> Paginators are a feature of boto3 that act as an abstraction over the
>   process of iterating over an entire result set of a truncated API
>   operation.

Reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html

See an snippet below:

```
def get_all_volumes(session):
    volumes = []

    ec2 = session.client("ec2")
    # Get all Volumes using paginator
    paginator = ec2.get_paginator("describe_volumes")
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate()
    for page in page_iterator:
        volumes.extend(page["Volumes"])
    return volumes
```

Comment: You also need to poll each region, since they are all independent.