# Handle JSON returned from Subprocess

Tags: python, json

I'm running a call to AWS CLI: `aws ec2 describe-volumes --query Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId}` which returns json:

```
[
  {
    "ID": "vol-123456789101112"
  }
]
```

I'm calling it from python's subprocess function:

```
command = subprocess.run('aws ec2 describe-volumes --query Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId}', shell=True, capture_output=True)
output = command.stdout
```

Which outputs: `b'[\r\n    {\r\n        "ID": "vol-123456789101112"\r\n    }\r\n]\r\n'`

Is there a better approach to collecting this json, then making it easier to parse and collect the individual IDs if several are returned.

Comment: What you have should be pretty easy to parse as it is, no? Does `json.loads(command.stdout)` not work? What's the specific problem you encounter when you try?

Comment: The only thing in your code I would describe as thoroughly bad practice is using `shell=True`; it would be much more appropriate to use `['aws', 'ec2', 'describe-volumes', '--query', 'Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId}']` as your command, and then not need to worry about whether the current shell will mangle the query on its way through to the aws command.

Comment: Could be done with boto as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002826/list-ec2-volumes-in-boto

Comment: (the other way to ensure that your data won't get mangled even if you _do_ use `shell=True` is to use proper quoting in your shell command; `"aws ec2 describe-volumes --query 'Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId}'"` is safe, insofar as it's well-defined that no POSIX-compliant shell will modify the content of that single-quoted string).

Comment: why not using boto3 directly?

Comment: @balderman how did I not come across this. Thanks haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess` returns `bytes` by default on Python 3. If you expect text, try adding `text=True` to the keyword arguments. (`json` will accept `bytes` just fine, but if you want to inspect the result before parsing it, you can easily get rid of the unnerving `b` prefix.)

```py
command = subprocess.run(
     ['aws', 'ec2', 'describe-volumes', '--query', 'Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId}'],
     check=True, text=True, capture_output=True)
```

Notice also the addition of `check=True` and the refactoring to remove the unnecessary and wasteful `shell=True`.

Comment: `json.loads()` works fine with the bytestring, though, so I really don't know what the problem the OP meant to be asking about was.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, added a comment about exactly that just as you wrote yours (-: